# JavaScript is not getting executed with an on-click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I had this JavaScript running for a while but I altered it a slight bit and now I cant get it to even run. I had an alert in the JavaScript for a while and I couldn't even get that to trigger. There is some PHP above this code but it shouldn't interfere with the JavaScript.

```
<form action="http://go.gbpi.net/Outage/add-question/" method="post">
Question Name (A descriptive name for the question. Example: "Phone number", or "Pizza Size"): <br /><input type="text" name="questionName" />
<?php
echo("Category: <br /><select name=\"category\" id=\"category\">");
$mysqli = db_init();
$mysqli->next_result();
    $cats = $mysqli->query("call GetActiveCategories()");
    while ($row = $cats->fetch_assoc()){
        $categori = $row['Category_Text'];
        if(!($categori == $category)){
        echo("<option value = \"".$categori."\">".$categori."</option>");}
    }
echo("</select>");
?>
Question Text:<br /><input type="text" name="questionText" style='width:80%' />
Question Type:<br /><select name="myList" id="myList" onchange="selectType(); return false;">
<option value = "1">Yes or No</option>
<option value = "2">Multiple Choice</option>
<option value = "3">Multiple Select</option>
<option value = "4">Open Response</option>
    <option value = "5">Final Reply</option>
    <option value = "6">Summary</option>
</select>
<div id='regexes'>
type of input: <br /><select name="regex" id="regex">
<option value = "-1">any input</option>
<?php
    $mysqli->next_result();
    $regexes = $mysqli->query("call GetValidRegexes()");
    while($regex_row = $regexes->fetch_assoc()){
        $rid = $regex_row['Validation_ID'];
        $rname = $regex_row['Validation_Name'];
        echo("<option value = \"".$rid."\">".$rname."</option>");
    }
?>
</select>
</div>
<div id='buttons'></div>
<button id="adda" onclick="addAnswer(); return false;">add answer (max: 10)</button>
<input type="submit" value="add question" />
</form>
    <?php
            echo("<a href='./define-relationships/'>Define Question Relationships</a><br />");
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("adda").style.visibility="hidden";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var answers = 0;
var inHTML = "";
function addAnswer()
{
if(answers < 10){
write = document.getElementById('buttons');
write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML + "answer: <input type=\"text\" name=\"answer" + answers + "\" /> <br>";
answers = answers + 1;}
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function selectType()
{
alert("HAHA I HATE YOU!");
var type=document.getElementById("myList").value;
if(type == "2" || type == "3"){
    document.getElementById("buttons").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("adda").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("regexes").style.visibility="hidden";
}
else if(type == "4"{
    document.getElementById("buttons").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("adda").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("regexes").style.visibility="visible";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("buttons").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("adda").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("regexes").style.visibility="hidden";
}}
</script>
```

Comment: Please show what the **browser** sees....

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Have you looked for error messages in the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jquery and/or source control?

Comment: If you can't take the time to accept an answer on one of your 6 other questions, why should I take the time to answer this one?

Comment: Read the FAQ and learn how to accept answers to your questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: it says that there is a reference error in my "onchange" in the select object, i'm not using jquery because most of our stuff is already done in php. The reference error baffles me because it was working fine before.

Comment: PHP is server-side, JavaScript/jQuery is client-side (it runs in the client's browser).  You can use both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a jsfiddle it's hard to know for sure if this is the problem, but you have a syntax error in the last script on the page.

```
else if(type == "4"{
```

Add the closing paren and see if that helps.

Comment: thaks for pointing that out, turns out I have another error in the php above the section i listed that i hadnt seen yet.